# Why does String class extends Object

Tags: java, string

Looking at the `String` class declaration , you can see that it extends `Object` class.

```
public final class String
extends Object
implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

What is the point of explicitly writing `extends Object` where it actually isn't required ?

is their any logical reason behind this ?

Comment: It's ancient Java history, go to an archaeological site to ask :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't in the official oracle JDK source code. Which version are you looking at?

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

Either way, it wouldn't make a difference whether you wrote `extends Object` or not in the source code. Beware though, if you had to extend another legitimate class instead of `Object`, you'll hit a dead end as Java doesn't support multiple inheritence.

### Update

The OP is looking at the declaration of String in the API documentation. Every class in Java must and do extend Object. However, it is a different thing whether the source code says `extends Object`.

The `String` class doesn't have `extends Object` in the source code. However, the API declaration always indicates that every class extends Object implicitly.

Have a look at the [source code](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html).

Comment: Well, that's not the source code. Every class in Java implicitly extends Object. Nobody normally explicitly declares it as `extends Object`.

Comment: Ahh.. I completely missed that i was looking at docs and not at the actual source.

Comment: Just rephrase your question using [`Character`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java/#120) as an example and it is correct. However, in OpenJDK 7 they have removed the `extends Object` designation.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you don't have installed the JDK sources but are looking at the decompiled class file.

In my source folder, the `extends Object` is missing. The decompiler would just always add `extends <superclass>`. But since in Java every class is by definition derived from Object, this will become `extends Object` in the case of the String class.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @loki To be fair, this could have turned out to be the correct explanation. The actual source code of String does not declare "extends Object".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Agree. Read question few more times to exactly understand it.