# String implement in Oracle JDK and OpenJDK

Tags: java, string, generics

I found the definition about String:

- Oracle Jdk: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
- Open Jdk: http://docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html

`String` in `Oracle Jdk` `extends Object` but `Open Jdk` doesn't

And when i create an example code with generic type as:

```
    public void testMethod(Map<String,?> map)
    Map<String,String> tmpMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tmpMap.put("Test", "Test");
    testMethod(tmpMap);
```

it compile and run without any errors on two platforms.

? in `Generic` is any types which extends from `Object`

So my question is:

- There are some mistakes when creating Open Jdk document or i am misunderstanding about Generic or String type in Java?

**See also:**

- [Why does String class extends Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533207/why-does-string-class-extends-object)

Comment: Wait, what's the issue? All class types extend `Object` implicitly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis String in Open Jdk does not extends Object class :-)

Comment: All class types extend `Object` **implicitly**.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, but in Open Jdk document, `String` does not extends Object type :-)

Comment: @RongNguyen: you need to fetch a dictionary and look for the meaning of the word "implicitly".

Comment: @vanza I understand this word, and i also understand `All class types extend Object implicitly`. Thank for your reply, now i know the reason !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2) says

> The class`Object` is a superclass (§8.1.4) of **all** other classes.

So a class declared as

```
public class SomeType
```

is actually equivalent to

```
public class SomeType extends Object
```

So the `String` class from your OpenJDK Java 7 link

```
public final class String implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

is actually equivalent to

```
public final class String extends Object implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

So that satisfies the Javadoc in the Oracle link.